# Java RMI: ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, connection, rmi, connectexception

I realize this question has been asked many times and answered many times (often from EJP, who clearly knows his stuff!), but I am still struggling.

I have "stolen" a simple RMI Adding Server and Client.
(Thank you, 
http://www.scs.ryerson.ca/mes/courses/cps530/programs/rmi/Schildt/addTwoNumbers.html who then gives credit to Chapter 24 of "Java 2: The Complete Reference" by P.Naughton and H.Schildt.)

No matter what I try I still get this "Connection timed out" Exception.
Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

I suspect that there's something going on with the firewall, but if so, I don't know what to tell my IT guys to fix and change.

Thanks in advance!

Interface:

```
public interface AddServerIntf extends Remote {
    double add(double d1, double d2) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Server:

```
public class SimpleRMIExServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
        System.out.println("Class name " + SimpleRMIExServer.class.getSimpleName());
        System.out.println("Path " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase",
                "file:///D:\\SimpleRMIExample\\lib\\SimpleRMIExample.jar");
        Registry registry;
        try {
            registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        } catch (RemoteException remoteException) {
            registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099);
        }
        AddServerImpl addServerImpl = new AddServerImpl();
        registry.bind("AddServer", addServerImpl);
        System.out.println("Located Registry " + registry.toString());
        for (String boundName : registry.list()) {
            System.out.println("Name bound: " + boundName);
        }
        Naming.rebind("SERVERNAME", addServerImpl);
        System.out.println("Registry: " + registry);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Remote: " + addServerImpl);
    }    
}
public class AddServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements AddServerIntf {
    public AddServerImpl() throws RemoteException {
    }

    @Override
    public double add(double d1, double d2) throws RemoteException {
        return d1 + d2;
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class SimpleRMIExClient {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     final Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("SERVERNAME", 1099);
     AddServerIntf addServerIntf = (AddServerIntf) registry.lookup("AddServer");
     System.out.println("The first number is: " + 10);
     double d1 = Double.valueOf(10).doubleValue();
     System.out.println("The second number is: " + 15);
     double d2 = Double.valueOf(15).doubleValue();
     System.out.println("The sum is: " + addServerIntf.add(d1, d2)); //Exception occurs here.
   }
}
```

Output From Server:

```
D:\>java -jar SimpleRMIExServer.jar
Class name SimpleRMIExServer
Path D:\
Located Registry RegistryImpl[UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[XX.XX.XX.XX:
1099](local),objID:[0:0:0, 0]]]]
Name bound: AddServer
Registry: RegistryImpl[UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[XX.XX.XX.XX:1099](l
ocal),objID:[0:0:0, 0]]]]

Remote: AddServerImpl[UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[XX.XX.XX.XX:54119](l
ocal),objID:[2a7202aa:14492e5ea89:-7fff, -5034491972061237368]]]]
```

Output From Client:

```
debug:
The first number is: 10
The second number is: 15
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: XX.XX.XX.XX; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.add(Unknown Source)
    at simplermiexclient.SimpleRMIExClient.main(SimpleRMIExClient.java:35)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 7 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 33 seconds)
```

Additionally, I used the command netstat -a and it showed:

```
LocalAddress       ForeignAddress    State
0.0.0.0:1099       SERVERNAME:0      LISTENING
[::]:1099          SERVERNAME:0      LISTENING
XX.XX.XX.XX:53373  SERVERNAME:1099   ESTABLISHED
```

(Among many other lines)
I have also seen:

```
LocalAddress       ForeignAddress    State
XX.XX.XX.XX:54138   SERVERNAME:1099  TIME_WAIT
```

**Edit:**
I tried adding in:

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "SERVERNAME");
```

to the server right after setting the codebase System property, based on EJP's recommendation to so many others to read Java RMI FAQ A.1.

When I did, this was the stack trace:

```
debug:
The first number is: 10
The second number is: 15
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: SERVERNAME; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.add(Unknown Source)
    at simplermiexclient.SimpleRMIExClient.main(SimpleRMIExClient.java:35)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 7 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 15 seconds)
```

Answering my own question:
I have figured out the answer to my problem.  I love to see others do that, it's good to be able to say it myself.

My final solution was a firewall problem, but I'd like to provide suggestions to anyone out there for HOW I solved my problem.

1. **Break it down.** Take my code above that really isn't my code and make a much simpler version of the RMI server and test it.
2. **Start small and work your way up.** Start with localhost make sure that works, then test on a separate PC (I had a virtual PC), then test on your server.
3. **GET HELP!**  I searched the Internet A LOT. Thank you, EJP!  Also, once I finally got it working on the Virtual PC, but not on the server, then I go my IT guys involved and they found a difference between the two.  "There was a firewall setting on the PC that was related to Java that was not set on the server." - IT Guy (See: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communicate-through-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7)

I realize what I've said here is nothing new and I know I've heard it many times, but sometimes it takes hearing it a thousand times to finally accept.  Although it hasn't worked with my kids yet. ;-)

Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

(Answered by a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Answering my own question: I have figured out the answer to my problem. I love to see others do that, it's good to be able to say it myself.
>
> My final solution was a firewall problem, but I'd like to provide suggestions to anyone out there for HOW I solved my problem.
>
> 1. **Break it down.** Take my code above that really isn't my code and make
>      a much simpler version of the RMI server and test it.
> 2. **Start small and work your way up.** Start with localhost make sure
>      that works, then test on a separate PC (I had a virtual PC), then
>      test on your server.
> 3. **GET HELP!** I searched the Internet A LOT. Thank you, EJP! Also, once
>      I finally got it working on the Virtual PC, but not on the server,
>      then I go my IT guys involved and they found a difference between
>      the two. "There was a firewall setting on the PC that was related to
>      Java that was not set on the server." - IT Guy (See:
>      http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communicate-through-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7
>      )
>
> I realize what I've said here is nothing new and I know I've heard it many times, but sometimes it takes hearing it a thousand times to finally accept. Although it hasn't worked with my kids yet. ;-)
>
> Good Luck.